# Selenium 3.0+gecko: Se borra el texto escrito en la caja de texto

Tags: c#, selenium

Utilizando selenium 3.0 junto con gecko, la aplicación se ejecuta aparentemente bien pero al llegar al rellenado de texto en una caja, escribe el texto y lo borra antes de poder utilizarlo en el siguiente paso. Sucede en búsquedas, login...
Antes de la actualización de versión todo funcionaba bien.
Código de ejemplo:
*

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys(CurrentValidationTest.User);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(CurrentValidationTest.Password);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();
```

*
¿Alguien sabe cómo resolverlo? Alguien tuvo algúm problema parecido?